# Communication betweeh BHO and Explorer Bar

Tags: internet-explorer, com, bho

I've a IE Explorer bar (Band object) with lots of UI and communication to server which I would like to implement in C# (.NET). I also have a BHO with all kind of DOM manipulation and events which I would like to implement in C++ (using ATL).
What should be the best way to communicate between these two components. Given that a single process can have several of those (Explorer Bar and BHO ***per tab***), the pairing has to somehow facilitate IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IE to facilitate connections, for example you can call IWebBrowser2::PutProperty to store the automation interface of your BHO and retrieve it in your explore bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an object and register it in the [Running Object Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then coordinate communication from there.

You could use any form of IPC at this point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Registry for this.  The registry can handle a large payload, and it is fast and reliable, and you have the rights to access it.  If your process had the privileges and you want a faster throughput I'd say go with named pipes.  But your hands are tied as a BHO.  (I presume anyway, I haven't actually tried to register a named pipe in a BHO process.)

"the pairing has to somehow facilitate IE."  IE does not care - have each process generate its own GUID, and then create a registry key with that GUID as the name.